# Redirect from domain root folder to subdomain folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, root

I´d like to redirect all images with name ending ("-554-380"):
Subdomain called: http://static.domain.de

`http://domain.de/../..-554-380` -- redirect --> `http://static.domain.de/images/..-554-380`

My root .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_HIDPI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1-554x380.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(static/images.+)-277x190\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1-554x380.$2 [NC,L]
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?-554-380)$ http://static.domain.de/images/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_HIDPI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1-554x380.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(static/images.+)-277x190\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1-554x380.$2 [NC,L]
```

**UPDATE:** As per comments:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)-277x190\.(jpe?g|png)$ /$1-554x380.$2 [NC,L] [L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just to chance just this rule, with the right part of the subdomain or? But I don´t know the syntax for this. `RewriteRule ^(static/images.+)-277x190\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1-554x380.$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you mean by `I have just to chance just this rule, with the right part of the subdomain or?` Can you clarify your problem a bit?

Comment: I cant´t "translate" `RewriteRule ^(http://static.domain.de/images.+)-277x190\..` intro .htaccess compatible syntax.